# Migrating MySQL database to Firebird Server 2.5

Tags: mysql, firebird

I have a MySQL 5.5 database that I wish to migrate to Firebird Server 2.5. I have no issues with an existing MySQL database but after MySQL's acquisition, I am worried about the unavailability of Community Edition any time soon.

I want to migrate to a true and robust RDBMS like Firebird. PostgreSQL is another choice, but it's .NET provider is sluggish.

Is there any free tool to migrate existing MySQL database to Firebird? I also want to know how Firebird fits in terms of performance when compared with MySQL.

Comment: That's more of a http://serverfault.com oriented question.

Comment: There's already free ports of MySQL including MariaDB and Percona.  Do you really want to go through the trouble of a conversion for something that may happen with MySQL even though we already have really active forks?

Comment: There has always been a confusion in StackOverflow. When people see a word like SERVER, the post is kicked to ServerFault when the post is most suited for StackOverflow itself.

Comment: see my answer [here][1] for a inverse answer, but still completely relevant


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478374/need-to-import-fdb-data-file-into-mysql-database/16338003#16338003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Clever Components' Interbase DataPump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp) with success. I personally haven't used it with MySQL, but there shouldn't be any problems.

As of perfomance comparison - as always it comes down to your specific data and use cases. General wisdom is that MySQL is faster in some cases but it comes with the cost of reliability (ie not using transactions).

Comment: I guess, MySQL has Transactions support now.

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK one can choose not to use it which is not the case with FB.

Answer (score 2):

I also use Clever Components Interbase DataPump but you can also check IBPhoenix ressource site [here](http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/search/doc_320)