# Need to import fdb data file into mysql database

Tags: mysql, import, fdb

How can I import .fdb file into mysql database?

Comment: Have you tried any tools, perhaps [DatabaseWorkbench](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.mysql.php) could be of use to you?

Comment: or http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could find useful was to use [Exportizer Pro    5.5.4](http://www.vlsoftware.net/download.html)

It allows to export data to database, file, clipboard, or printer. Exportizer Pro works with databases via ADO, BDE, or Interbase/Firebird interfaces. It can open ODBC data sources, files of DB, DBF, MDB, ACCDB, XLS, XLSM, XLSB, GDB, IB, FDB, HTML, UDL, DBC, TXT, CSV types, and databases specified by ADO connection strings. Data can be exported to file formats like text, CSV, XLS, RTF, XML, HTML, DBF, SQL script, and to relational database of any type supported by ADO, BDE, or Interbase. For example, it is possible to perform such popular database conversions as dbf to txt, txt to xls, dbf to csv, txt to dbf, Access to HTML, Excel to Access, Interbase to MySQL, and much more.

It is possible to export all or selected database files from a folder or all or selected tables from a database at once.

Exportizer Pro can automatically detect the most known image types (JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP, ICO) in BLOB fields and export them, for example, to HTML. During the export, you can convert BLOB images to another image format.

Many export options ensure full control over output. There is an ability to specify the source-to-target field mappings.

Export operations can be performed either via the program interface or via command line with large number of parameters. You can easily generate needed command line directly from the GUI.

It is possible to copy data to clipboard or print them.

There are several utility functions for data manipulating and bookmarking.

So you use install it and then open fdb file, then select your table and export it using MYSQL 
[image]

Comment: This is awesome! It did exactly what I wanted. I wonder why do people still use so obscure and crappy RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

.fdb is a firebird database. the best way to migrate to mysql is two write a scripted application that will copy each record of each table from firebird into a duplicate framework in mysql. obviously mysql and firebird are two implementations of relational databases that suporrt many ANSI SQL standard features so you can SELECT from your firebird db and INSERT into you mysql db.

There is no need to invest in a propitiatory tool for this, or waste your time with an open source solution assuming you know basic sql and a little c++

The backbone of it is that in your application you will need to load the firebird record into memory using a select and then run an insert into your mysql DB. The Qt library contains everything you will need to make independent connections to these DBs.